# Best way to ask users to upload multiple files

Tags: forms, mobile, upload

I am having issues with the step where we ask for users to upload multiple files.

These are the 2 main issues: 
- Our system is quite old so we only can use the old way to let users to upload files ( browse file -> select file -> confirm to upload)instead of the current drag and drop box
- 50% of users upload sufficient files even though we have clear instructions on which types and how many files they need to upload.

Do you have any suggestions or examples on some good layouts for uploading several documents on one page ( especially mobile view)

I attached the screenshot of the page
[image]
[image]

Cheers,

Comment: Posts requesting suggestions and examples of good layouts are very broad and not necessarily useful in the long term. If you have a layout that you are planning to use and are experiencing some sort of problem with it then we can help you more.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by "_upload Ids ( not only , but many)_" (especially the bit in parentheses). My guess is one or more scans of drivers' license, passport etc., but you need to make this clear either way.

Comment: I am still not sure what the issue is. The layout seems straightforward to me, Could you clarify what you mean by *"several documents in one page"*?

Answer (score 3):

You could show the uploaded file as a list and allow your user to upload it live and remove it if they want.
if you give users to upload their file live (auto function):
1- the user could have able to re-download the file to double check the doc
2- The user could be able to remove the wrong file he/she uploaded.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Multiple files can be also uploaded asynchronously, as shown in [this example](http://demos.shieldui.com/web/upload/asynchronous).
The UI is very compact and you can add much additional description as required.

Answer (score 0):

The "Upload File" button attracts a lot of attention when there are no files to be uploaded. Perhaps disabling the button when there is no file being appointed to can help bring some focus back to the interactions that users should be focusing on. (This is assuming that a file upload is required for them to proceed to the next steps)

Another thing that might help, the system only takes 4 file types (pdf, jpeg, jpg, png). Listing the file types in list form or bullet points allows users to quickly scan and understand the information. It will also give more prominence to the requirements, since putting them in bullet points means it will take up more space.